# sharepoint ajax postback randomly fails in chrome

Tags: ajax

I have a page that works fine in IE, Firefox and Safari but the postback intermittently will not work in Chrome. Here is information for the page:

Sharepoint 2010

Custom webpart running in a webpart page

URL - http://www.co.st-clair.il.us/Pages/parcel.aspx

using ajax control toolkit

What I'm seeing is the page will intermittently not work. What I'm seeing when using the chrome developer tools is that there are scripts that are not loading on page load. On the chrome developer console I select "Network" and view "Scripts". when the page loads, there should be 26 scripts that load. Intermittently, only 13 will load. When the scripts do not load, the postbacks do not fire at all. there is a submit button and a dropdown that causes a postback, neither one do anything.

Any ideas on why Chrome is not loading all the scripts?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue and will hopefully be addressed in SP2 of SharePoint 2010. Here are possible workarounds:

[ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded too slow in Firefox and Chrome](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/57883/executeordelayuntilscriptloaded-too-slow-in-firefox-and-chrome)