# In Chrome, Async Postbacks Fail

Tags: javascript, ajax, chrome

In Google Chrome, inside of an Update Panel, the first async postback succeeds, but the second silently fails.

The issue is discussed many places:

- http://www.marten-online.com/sharepoint/ajax-second-postback-not-working-in-sharepoint-in-updatepanel.html
- [sharepoint ajax postback randomly fails in chrome](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/70538/sharepoint-ajax-postback-randomly-fails-in-chrome)
- [ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded too slow in Firefox and Chrome](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/57883/executeordelayuntilscriptloaded-too-slow-in-firefox-and-chrome)

And there is even a workaround in JavaScript:

```
_spOriginalFormAction=document.forms[0].action;_spSuppressFormOnSubmitWrapper=true;
```

But unfortunately, the above script also breaks SharePoint's multiple file upload dialog in IE.

Does anyone know of an alternative workaround?

Comment: Wrap that code in a conditional browser check so it doesn't affect IE?

Comment: That is so dirty, but it is exactly what we ended up doing... You might as well post the answer so i can vote it up :)

Comment: Post your own code, while my answer might be "correct" in this sense, your code would be more valuable and should be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up injecting some user-agent sniffing for Chrome.

```
if (Request != null && Request.UserAgent != null && Request.UserAgent.Contains("Chrome"))
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(UserControlBase), "UpdatePanelFixup", "_spOriginalFormAction=document.forms[0].action;_spSuppressFormOnSubmitWrapper=true;", true);
}
```

I very much hate this solution, but I cannot find anything better. I would be every interested if someone had a better fix or had some special insight into Chrome compatibility.